# How can I deploy (create .ipa) iphone app using 'cordova build ios --release'?

Tags: cordova, deployment, ipa

I have created a 'helloworld' iOS app with `cordova` using there [documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html). The app successfully runs when I run `cordova emulate ios`. What I can't do, is while deploying when I run `cordova build --release`. It doesn't create any `.ipa` files there. All I find is a `Helloworld.build` file in the `PROJECT_ROOT/platforms/ios/build` directory. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

I found this command which worked for me:

```
cordova build ios --device
cd platforms/ios/build/device
/usr/bin/xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication "$(pwd)/$PROJECT_NAME.app" -o "$(pwd)/$PROJECT_NAME.ipa"
```

Source: http://www.splinter.com.au/xcode-4-command-line-builds-of-iphone-apps/

I did run @MD. Mohiuddin Ahmed's Ruby script first, which would have changed my xcodeproj file. I'm not sure if that was necessary but I don't think so.

**Update for XCode 8**: As a commenter has noted, `PackageApplication` has been removed from XCode 8. To update the process, see the question: [What's the replacement for Xcode's PackageApplication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43094380/whats-the-replacement-for-xcodes-packageapplication)

*Edited to clarify process by adding `cordova build` command as suggested by comments.*

Comment: Right answer. Just to clarify: run `cordova build ios --device` to generate the app in `platforms/ios/build/device`

Comment: Yes that works great using `cordova build ios --device`

Comment: For some reason the `xcrun` line wasn't necessary for me.. I'm using Cordova 6, was it integrated into `cordova build ios --device` perhaps? When I ran that, it seems to have generated a properly signed ipa file using my XCode settings.

Comment: Seems PackageApplication is removed from xcode8, doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 47):

If you are using cordova ios 3.9.0 or newer, you can use this command to create the `.ipa` directly from the CLI with no extra commands:

```
cordova build ios --device --release
```

You'll need a `build.json` file on the root of your project

```
{
  "ios": {
    "debug": {
      "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
      "provisioningProfile": "your-dev-provisioning-profile-UUID-here"
    },
    "release": {
      "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Distribution",
      "provisioningProfile": "your-distribution-provisioning-profile-UUID-here"
    }
  }
}
```

To get the UUID I open the `.mobileprovision` file on a text editor and search for 'UUID', not sure if there is an easier way of finding it.

If using Xcode 8 the `build.json` needs `developmentTeam` field and `packageType` field, but not longer need the provisioning profile, also, the `codeSignIdentity` should be `iPhone Developer` for both debug and release:

```
{
    "ios": {
        "debug": {
            "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
            "developmentTeam": "FG35JLLMXX4A",
            "packageType": "development"
        },
        "release": {
            "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
            "developmentTeam": "FG35JLLMXX4A",
            "packageType": "app-store"
        }
    }
}
```

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/guide/platforms/ios/index.html#using-buildjson

Comment: Just as an FYI, this was not working for me. I mean it created a .app but not .ipa file. Turned out my iOS platform was 3.8, which is now out of date. An easy mistake to make so watch out for it.

Comment: Updated, this feature was added on cordova ios 3.9.0

Comment: This is much better options.. as it needs one time setting..!! !

Comment: NB/ UUID can be found in itunes by clicking on the serial number a few times or executing $ ios-deploy -c in the terminal if you have ios-deploy installed

Comment: I talk about the  provisioning profile (.mobileprovision) UUID, not the device UUID

Comment: Note: with the latest (dev) release the required content of the build.json has changed. Please refer to the cordova documentation for more information

Comment: @CWBudde have you read the part about Xcode 8? it explains how to use with latest cordova and Xcode 8 and also links the docs. I don't think there has been more changes

Comment: @jcesarmobile it's no longer necessary to provide the provisioning profile UUID. However, if using SWIFT based plugins further build flags should be added. Read about the latest changes here: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/guide/platforms/ios/index.html#xcode-build-flags

Answer (score 5):

I finally figured out a way to automate this by using [xcodeproj](http://rubydoc.info/gems/xcodeproj), xcode and this ruby script :

```
require 'xcodeproj'
xcproj = Xcodeproj::Project.open("HelloWorld.xcodeproj")
xcproj.recreate_user_schemes
xcproj.save
```

And then in the `PROJECT_ROOT/platforms/ios/` directory this command helped me to generate my `*.ipa`:

```
xcodebuild -project HelloWorld.xcodeproj -exportArchive -exportFormat ipa -archivePath $(pwd)/HelloWorld.xcarchive -exportPath $(pwd)/HelloWorld.ipa CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO -alltargets -configuration Release
```

Thought we can sign our .**ipa** later on  :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try a new tool from http://fir.im.

They have a fir cli tool written in ruby. You can install it with the following command:

```
sudo gem install fir-cli --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

Sign up an account (all free like the good old testflight) and get a token from your profile. From your command prompt run:

```
fir login
```

Provide your token.

CD into your directory where your .xcodeproj located.

```
fir build_ipa .
```

After a while (if the build success) you will find your ipa in your ./build_ipa folder.

Comment: don't sent verification code for registration

Answer (score 1):

Everything else did not work for me but this works for me

```
cordova build ios
```

then

```
cordova run ios --device
```

The .ipa file is located at

```
myPrject/platforms/ios/build/device/myProject.ipa
```

build.json (set automatic siging)

```
{
    "ios": {
        "debug": {
            "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
            "developmentTeam": "FG35JLLMXX4A",
            "packageType": "development",
            "automaticProvisioning": true,
            "buildFlag": [
                "EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT = YES",
                "ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES=NO",
                "LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = \"@executable_path/Frameworks\""
            ]
        },
        "release": {
            "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
            "developmentTeam": "FG35JLLMXX4A",
            "packageType": "app-store",
            "automaticProvisioning": true,
            "buildFlag": [
                "EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT = YES",
                "ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES=NO",
                "LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = \"@executable_path/Frameworks\""
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Reference [docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/)

Voila!