# To install an app in a iphone

Tags: xcode, cordova

i created an app with apache cordova in windows pc, now i am trying to install this app in a iphone, so i get a mac and I downloaded xcode and now i do not know how to install my app in the iphone, please help me, it is very important, i read this page, but did not solve the problem
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/it/latest/guide/platforms/ios/

I tried to install sdk through the shell but I did not succeed

Comment: Your question is too broad. Which step you're having trouble in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your que is very broad can't provide the specific solution but you can try the below steps.

Install Xcode on your machine, first try to run your application on simulator, if it works fine there, then try to deploy it on the mac device. follow some links below, may help you out.

[How can I deploy (create .ipa) iphone app using 'cordova build ios --release'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24061063/how-can-i-deploy-create-ipa-iphone-app-using-cordova-build-ios-release)

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/testing.html