# Ionic / Cordova: I need a new app ID

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an existing app that I've been working on, but recently got approved for Apple Enterprise and when I try to deploy, it says my bundle ID is not unique (because I used it when I deployed with Apple Developer, not Enterprise).

**Is there a way to generate a new ID for an existing app?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bundle Identifiers are unique in Apple ecosystem. You want to have an enterprise distrubition of app. Apple guidelines

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps.html

Once you have the write provisional profile and new bundle identifier for enterprise deployment. you need to put new *AppId* to config.xml and build your iOS app. This way AppStore and Enterprise version of your apps willhave 2 different bundle identifiers and can be installed on same device.

Possibly you will want to automate this build process .

you can read how to create *ipa* file on here

[How can I deploy (create .ipa) iphone app using 'cordova build ios --release'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24061063/how-can-i-deploy-create-ipa-iphone-app-using-cordova-build-ios-release)

i would extend cordova build system and have

`cordova build ios --release` // app store release

`cordova build ios --enterprise-release`  // enterprise release